# Use Ionic or Cordova?

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

We want to build a simple application that use a lot of videos and images. The application should run on different mobile devices running Andriod and iPhone operating systems. Does Ionic also convert each application to all mobiles options ?

What do you suggest to use Cordova or Ionic?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**edit**: *This answer is an update to Ionic framework version 3:*

Disclaimer: This will sound like advertisement, so I have to say I'm in no way affiliated with Ionic, I just happen to like it so much that I'm sharing the love for it.

Ionic is so much more than “just” an UI framework. Ionic allows you to:

- have truly **only one single codebase** and deploy to iOS, Android, and Windows, along with the mobile web as a Progressive Web App
- generate icons and splash screens for all devices and device sizes with a single command: `ionic cordova resources`. This alone saves you at least a day of image preparing for various sizes.
- instantly update your apps with code changes, even when running directly on your device with `ionic cordova run --livereload`
- build and test iOS and Android versions side-by-side and see changes instantly with `ionic lab`
- share your Ionic apps with clients, customers, and testers all around the world without ever going through the App Store with `ionic upload`
- easily access the full native functionality of the device using [Ionic Native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/)
- Also, [Drifty](http://drifty.com/) (the team behind the Ionic framework) is building a full-stack backend services and tools for your Ionic app like [Live updating](https://ionicframework.com/products/#updates) (for deploying a new version without going through Apple review process! - **this is huge!**), [Push notifications](https://docs.ionic.io/services/push/), [Cloud packaging](https://ionicframework.com/products/#packaging), [Ionic Creator](https://creator.ionic.io) etc.
- Ionic CLI (command line interface) uses Cordova in the backend and allows you to build (directly using Ionic CLI) apps for iOS and Android (just by doing `ionic cordova build ios` or `ionic cordova build android`).
- Ionic uses Angular as a frontend framework so if you’re familiar with it, it will come as a bonus. Yes, the newest version of Ionic (currently 3) uses the newest and coolest Angular (currently 4) (*which was a total rewrite from the Angular 1 version*)
- All in all, I personally think Ionic framework has a bright future, so if nothing else – give it a try I bet you’ll like the ease of making an app with it.

---

This is the previous answer which covered Ionic 1

*Disclamer: This will sound like advertisement, so I have to say I'm in no way affiliated with Ionic, I just happen to like it so much that I'm sharing the love for it.*

Ionic is so much more than "just" an UI framework. Ionic allows you to:

- [generate icons and splash screens](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/create-icons-and-splash-screen-automatically-with-ionic-resources/) for all devices and device sizes with a single command: `ionic resources`. This alone saves you at least a day of image preparing for various sizes.
- instantly update your apps with code changes, even when running directly on your device with `ionic run --livereload`
- build and test iOS and Android versions side-by-side and see changes instantly with `ionic serve --lab`
- share your Ionic apps with clients, customers, and testers all around the world without ever going through the App Store with `ionic share`
- easily accessing the full native functionality of the device using ngCordova (here you get to use any Cordova plugin - so Ionic is indeed much more than Cordova per se)

Also, they're building a full-stack backend services and tools for your Ionic app like [Deploy](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/ionic-deploy-alpha-enables-app-update-on-the-fly/) (for deploying a new version without going through Apple review process!), [Analytics](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/ionic-analytics-alpha-lets-you/), [Push notifications](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-push-alpha/).

Ionic CLI (command line interface) uses Cordova in the backend and allows you to build (directly using Ionic CLI) apps for iOS and Android (you by doing `ionic build ios` or `ionic build android` and woila).

Ionic uses Angular as a frontend framework so if you're familiar with it it will come as a bonus. They're [working closely with the Angular 2.0 team](http://blog.ionic.io/angular-2-ionic/) too.

All in all, I personally think Ionic has a bright future, so if nothing else - give it a try I bet you'll like the ease of making an app with it.

Comment: It's great, but Ionic doesn't help to build on BlackBerry or Windows Phone. In contrast, Cordova supports all platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Both.

Make your app pretty with Ionic, and it uses Cordova to wrap it for the platforms you wish.

Ionic is a superset of Cordova.

Comment: Why use Cordova to wrap it if Ionic already supports that?

Comment: Sure, I know that, and thus my elaborated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ionic is a UI framework which operates on top of Cordova. Cordova is lower-level, Ionic is built to be used with Cordova.

Comment: Can I develop om ionic and still the application could run on all the mobile operation ?

Comment: @user1365697: please take a look at my answer. Yes, you can build your app for any Android or iPhone device. And, even they have Windows Phone planned in the future.