# Why Ionic, or another such library, for hybrid apps?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, cordova, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I'm building a mobile web app that I very soon intend to convert to a PhoneGap based hybrid app. Every resource and example I have read uses Ionic or a similar toolset to help with layout etc.

Now in my prototype app, bootstrap - and my design - is doing very well at making the app responsive and equally usable on my phone and on my laptop. Why introduce a third tool? I understand that PhoneGap itself provides hooks into the mobiles native resources like the camera, or does Ionic also take part in this bridging process?

Comment: some people don't have enough design or UI skills (or time), so they have to use a 3rd party UI frameworks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually answered a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179211/use-ionic-or-cordova/31180666#31180666):

An answer which will, I hope, solve your doubts and in the end you'll choose and love Ionic.

*Disclamer: This will sound like advertisement, so I have to say I'm in no way affiliated with Ionic, I just happen to like it so much that I'm sharing the love for it.*

Ionic is so much more than "just" an UI framework. Ionic allows you to:

- [generate icons and splash screens](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/create-icons-and-splash-screen-automatically-with-ionic-resources/) for all devices and device sizes with a single command: `ionic resources`. This alone saves you at least a day of image preparing for various sizes.
- instantly update your apps with code changes, even when running directly on your device with `ionic run --livereload`
- build and test iOS and Android versions side-by-side and see changes instantly with `ionic serve --lab`
- share your Ionic apps with clients, customers, and testers all around the world without ever going through the App Store with `ionic share`
- easily accessing the full native functionality of the device using ngCordova (here you get to use any Cordova plugin - so Ionic is indeed much more than Cordova per se)

Also, they're building a full-stack backend services and tools for your Ionic app like [Deploy](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/ionic-deploy-alpha-enables-app-update-on-the-fly/) (for deploying a new version without going through Apple review process!), [Analytics](http://www.nikola-breznjak.com/blog/ionic/ionic-analytics-alpha-lets-you/), [Push notifications](http://blog.ionic.io/announcing-ionic-push-alpha/).

Ionic CLI (command line interface) uses Cordova in the backend and allows you to build (directly using Ionic CLI) apps for iOS and Android (you by doing `ionic build ios` or `ionic build android` and woila).

Ionic uses Angular as a frontend framework so if you're familiar with it it will come as a bonus. They're [working closely with the Angular 2.0 team](http://blog.ionic.io/angular-2-ionic/) too.

All in all, I personally think Ionic has a bright future, so if nothing else - give it a try I bet you'll like the ease of making an app with it.

Comment: I will definitely try it, today still. A fun little app for gematria, with very few screens, then I can replace all the bootstrap with Ionic, and work as many as possible of Ionics tricks.

Comment: Just wanted to mention that I'm finding icon very easy to use because of the Angular 2 association.  If you've done any Angular 2 work you'll find ionic easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

These type of frameworks are used to avoid all the problems which happens when you use your web app in different devices/OS'es.

If really our app works smoothly in EVERY OS, then you don't need them, but to be honest, it's hard to belive it will work flawlessly in any environment unless it's a very basic app as each Web view on mobile devices has it's own quirks, in interaction and in representation.