# Using Cordova and AngularJS vs Ionic, which would be more recommended?

Tags: cordova, mobile, ionic-framework, hybrid-mobile-app

I am on the planning stages of a mobile application that we want to develop using web technologies.

The first idea that came to mind is using Cordova (and Visual Studio as an IDE, as recommended on the Ionic [Getting Started](http://ionicframework.com/getting-started/) page). That was before I understood that Cordova and Ionic were not interchangeable terms.

A little bit of more research helped me understand a little bit how [Cordova and Ionic defer](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-Cordova-and-Ionic/answer/Mirko-Nasato) (I'm still not 100% clear, but it helps).

My question is, if we are planning on developing a mobile app using web technologies, **including** AngularJS, what would be some advantages of using  Ionic or [ngCordova](http://ngcordova.com/), instead of using Cordova and finding a way implementing AngularJS?

And what would be the advantages of Ionic instead of ngCordova?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend you go with Ionic, and few months from now you may thank me.

Ionic, with their [Ionic Platform](http://ionic.io/platform) are offering you so much more awesome features like:

- [Live updates](http://ionic.io/platform#updates)
- [Push notifications](http://ionic.io/platform#notifications)
- [User authentication](http://ionic.io/platform#notifications)
- [Native builds](http://ionic.io/platform#packaging)

You also have access to their [Ionic Creator](https://creator.ionic.io/app/login) which is a tool for making prototypes by simply drag and dropping them on the canvas (as in Visual Studio for example).

You can also leverage [their Market](https://market.ionic.io/) where you can buy and sell your own plugins and templates.

On top of that, you have a [vibrant community](https://forum.ionicframework.com/) of developers on which you can lean on for help.

Honestly, I really am biased, but Ionic rocks <3

Btw, you can take a look at my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179211/use-ionic-or-cordova).

Comment: Are the features listed able to be added to a simple Cordova application?

Comment: Though this answer would require some additional explaining, let say that for the sake of an argument no, they can't.

Comment: For sake of argument i would say that even cordova have feature like push notification, user authentication plugin and Native builds too.